# How do I use a string as both a filename and a printed string when it contains an underscore?

Tags: pdftex, strings

In the code below, the second argument to `\examplecode` is simultaneously both the name of a file and the title of a frame. It fails when the filename contains an underscore.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\examplecode}[2]
{
    \mdfsetup{frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space #2 \space}}}

    \begin{mdframed}

    \inputminted[linenos,fontsize=\footnotesize,baselinestretch=.7]{#1}{src/#2}
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\examplecode{c}{testfile.c}    % ok
\examplecode{c}{test_file.c}   % error

\end{document}
```

How do I handle #2 so that it can be used for both these purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because you can't use `_` in text mode.
The easiest solution would be to redefine `\_` locally in your command:

```
\newcommand{\examplecode}[2]{
    \mdfsetup{frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space #2 \space}}}
    \begin{mdframed}
        \def\_{_}
        \inputminted[linenos,fontsize=\footnotesize,baselinestretch=.7]{#1}{src/#2}
    \end{mdframed}
}
```

and use it in the call:

```
\examplecode{c}{text\_file.c}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that `\def` affect anything outside the mdframed environment?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I've done this is to wrap the file name argument in another pair of curly brackets like:

```
\inputminted[linenos,fontsize=\footnotesize,baselinestretch=.7]{#1}{{src/#2}}
```